# freeze pane from row X to row Y

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to freeze **only from Row 10 to 12**

So When I start scrolling all the sheet will move until the row 10 reach the top of the frame, after that the scroll frame start at row 13 and always let row 10, 11, 12 visible at the top of the sheet.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Can you show what you try by your own? Please, edit your question and better explain what you try accomplishing. Are there rows 1 to 10 hidden? If not, do you want the code to hide them and let visible starting from 10 and 10 to 12 to be frozen? If not, what exactly do you try doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can only freeze panes on one spot, but if you're looking for something like this, you can obtain it using freeze panes (cell "A13") and hiding the rows from 1 to 9:

Scrollbar at the top:

[image]

After scrolling down:

[image]

Comment: Damn, that what I was afraid of, I have some datas to show from row 0 to 10. I can't just hide them sadly

Comment: Without freezing anything in my sheet is there any solution to just display the headers of my table, no matter where I am in this table ?

Comment: In order to show rows 1-10 : freeze "A11"; rows 1-12: freeze "A13"; rows 10-12: hide rows 1-9 and freeze "A13". Which rows do you want to see?

Comment: I have some importante informations until row 9 (I want to let them visible) and a table starting at row 10 (headers at row 10) with ~500 Rows and ~20 columns. I just want that my headers can stick to the top of the sheet when I scroll down into my table to always see them. So far I froze Row 1 to 10 to always display the table headers but like that half of my screen is locked on row 1 to 10 when only the row 10 is usefull.

Comment: So basically you want to see rows 1 to 10 but without it locking your entire screen. Did you already consider zooming out? :-) (Just Ctrl+Mouse-wheel)

Comment: sorry it seams that I have some difficulties to be clear, I want **my rows 1 to 10 visible** but **when I scroll down I only want the row 10 at the top of my sheet** event when I scroll until row 20000. (the row 10 are my headers and all rows > 10 are part of my table). If I scroll down that mean I don't need to see row 1 to 9 anymore.

Comment: Oh, that might be difficult: I have seen that, using `ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 24`, you can command your sheet to scroll up to row 24, but I don't find an event handler which is launched while you are scrolling. In case you find that, you might opt for something like `If ActiveWindow.ScrollRow >= 11 Then ActiveWindow.Rows[1].Hidden = True` (and making them visible in the other direction, of course).

Answer (score 1):

For a VBA solution, the below runs whenever the selection changes and will achieve what you're asking for.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Sel As Range, ScRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveWindow
    ScRow = .ScrollRow
    If .SplitRow = 0 And ScRow > 10 Then
        .ScrollRow = 10: Range("13:13").Select
        .FreezePanes = True
        .ScrollRow = ScRow + 3: Target.Select
    ElseIf .FreezePanes = True And ScRow <= 14 Then
        .FreezePanes = False
    End If
End With 'ActiveWindow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However a much simpler and more reliable solution would be to select your table's entire data range and press Ctrl+T to convert to a table (make sure 'my table has headers' box is ticked). This way when you scroll down, the column headers (A, B, C etc) are replaced by table column header names

Comment: Sadly my table is not a real one because of merged cell, but that's exactly what I want yes. I will try the VBA solution, thanks for the help.

Comment: this vba sub doesn't work on my side ... but maybe I missed something

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a VBA button to hide/show the row 1 to 9 when needed